# Clearcase protect -chmod +x recursively all *.exe

Tags: find, clearcase, chmod

I am trying to recursively change all .exe in a directory.

I did a bit more digging before posting and ended up finding what I needed.  Will post with my answer just on case anyone can used this information.  Hope that is alright I am new here.

```
ct find . -all -name *.bat -print -exec "cleartool protect -chmod +x -file ""%CLEARCASE_PN%"""
```

Comment: It seems a little odd to be keeping executables checked in to ClearCase; they are normally derived files and do not need to be version controlled. (The source that is used to create them should be version controlled, of course, but that's a different matter - and the source does not need to be executable, in general).

Comment: I work at a Medical Device company.  We keep just about everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you consider the [man page of `cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm), and the [additional examples of `cleartool find`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)

- `-all` generally for quite lengthy search, especially for large vob with a long history, so you want to add selection criteria to reduce the time, like '`-type f`' to only consider files.
- '`-print`' isn't necessary, except if you want the list of all .exe changed, but the simple fact to print each element can slow down the operation considerably.
- the additional quotations are needed to pick filenames that contain spaces, but you can use an escape notation, more readable: `\"`
- ct doesn't exist unless you define the alias for cleartool (in windows: `doskey ct=cleartool $*`)

So:

```
ct find . -all -type f -name "*.bat" -exec "cleartool protect -chmod +x -file \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

Comment: I do like your solution better.  I tried to give it an additional +1 but do not have the rep to do so.  Very detailed answer, thank you.