# How to search ClearCase repositories

Tags: search, clearcase

I just switched to use ClearCase and want to know if it has any build-in tool or plugin to do across VOBs search. I previously used Opengrok to index the Subversion and Git repositories by checking the head out nightly and I think I can do the same for Clearcase. But before that, I want to know if there is any existing ClearCase capability for so. I definitely can leverage the file system (i.e. Windows File Explorer) but it is not efficient enough for developers.

Or suggestions on any other good practice for searching ClearCase code will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to be more specific. Do you have to find out filenames? code lines? labels? branches? etc.

Answer (score 3):

The main option is [`cleartool find -avobs`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/find.htm), but the best practice is to limit the search to:

- one vobs
- the elements visible (meaning selected) by a specific ClearCase view

That is the fastest way to get results.

The IBM page "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)" illustrates many type of search you can do in a Vob.
I use some of them in:

- "[ClearCase find and exec with `%CLEARCASE_PN%` in `cmd` always returns same element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11331961/6309)"
- "[Find files in Clearcase view newer than a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7676484/6309)"
- "[Clearcase `protect -chmod +x` recursively all `*.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336752/6309)"